# Error using Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I get the error `"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/parboiled2/ParserInput` when I try to run any code which uses Akka Http.

I am using these Jar files:

```
akka-http-core_2.11-10.0.1.jar
akka-http_2.11-10.0.1.jar
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you working with Scala 2.11?

Comment: You are missing dependencies. In this case it is akka-parsing but you will be missing even more transitive dependencies. Try using some build tool which understands the dependency declaration to save you a lot of hassle :)

Comment: Agree with @jrudolph try using `SBT`.